# Traits class to extract container's value_type from a back_insert_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, type-traits, value-type, inserter

The `std::back_insert_iterator` has `value_type` equal to `void`, but it also has a `protected` member `container` that holds a pointer to the underlying `Container`. I am trying to write a traits class to extract the container's `value_type`, along these lines:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<class OutputIt>
struct outit_vt
:
    OutputIt
{
    using self_type = outit_vt<OutputIt>;
    using value_type = typename std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(std::declval<self_type>().container)>::value_type;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    auto it = std::back_inserter(v);
    static_assert(std::is_same<outit_vt<decltype(it)>::value_type, int>::value, "");
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/346eb54170341acc)

However, this (more or less expectedly) runs into incomplete type errors. Is there anyway around this in order to get extract the container's `value_type`?

Comment: Why don't you use a nested type that derives from the iterator? [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3547c063ddfb1ddb)

Comment: @dyp I was being daft, `back_insert_iterator` has a nested typedef `container_type` even

Comment: See recently added live example. -- ooooh that is a public member. I see

Comment: @dyp your live example is nice, but it also uses the nested typedef. When doing this with `declval` and the `container` member, you can e.g. make the parent class a friend of the helper class (that derives from the template parameter) and then get access to its protected member.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer by @Rapptz is correct but for generic code (i.e. when it is not clear a priori whether one deals with a raw `T*` or a `back_insert_iterator` or one of the Standard Library's other output iterators), a more systematic approach is necessary.

To that effect, below a definition of a class template `output_iterator_traits` in a user-defined `namespace xstd`.

```
#include <iterator>             // iterator, iterator_traits, input_iterator_tag, output_iterator_tag, random_access_iterator_tag
                                // back_insert_iterator, front_insert_iterator, insert_iterator, ostream_iterator, ostreambuf_iterator
#include <memory>               // raw_storage_iterator

namespace xstd {

template<class T>
struct output_iterator_traits
:
        std::iterator_traits<T>
{};

template< class OutputIt, class T>
struct output_iterator_traits<std::raw_storage_iterator<OutputIt, T>>
:
        std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, T>
{};

template<class Container>
struct output_iterator_traits<std::back_insert_iterator<Container>>
:
        std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, typename Container::value_type>
{};

template<class Container>
struct output_iterator_traits<std::front_insert_iterator<Container>>
:
        std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, typename Container::value_type>
{};

template<class Container>
struct output_iterator_traits<std::insert_iterator<Container>>
:
        std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, typename Container::value_type>
{};

template <class T, class charT, class traits>
struct output_iterator_traits<std::ostream_iterator<T, charT, traits>>
:
        std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, T>
{};

template <class charT, class traits>
struct output_iterator_traits<std::ostreambuf_iterator<charT, traits>>
:
        std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, charT>
{};

} // namespace xstd
```

The unspecialized version simply inherits from `std::iterator_traits<T>`, but for the 6 output iterators defined in the `<iterator>` and `<memory>` headers, the specializations inherit from `std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, V>` where `V` is the type appearing as an argument of the iterator's `operator=(const V&)`.

For the insert iterators, this corresponds to `typename Container::value_type`, for raw storage iterators to `T`, and for `ostream` and `ostreambuf` iterators to `T` and `charT`, respectively.

A generic algorithm of the form

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
auto my_fancy_algorithm(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt dest)
{
     using T = typename xstd::output_iterator_traits<OutputIt>::value_type;
     for (; first != last; ++first) {
         // ... construct arguments from *first
         *dest++ = T{ /* arguments */ };
     }
}
```

will then transparantly work with both raw pointers and the Standard Library's output iterators.

Comment: A very clean and STL-like solution, but what did you compile it with? I believe that default template arguments are not allowed in partial specializations.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [`container_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) that it has:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct outit_v {
    using container_type = typename T::container_type;
    using value_type = typename container_type::value_type;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    auto it = std::back_inserter(v);
    static_assert(std::is_same<outit_v<decltype(it)>::value_type, int>::value, "");
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72dd5cb4bc3fc143)